# How to deal with multiple "basedOn" elements in style definition?

Tags: openxml

I think the reference doesn't specify a max number of occurence of the "basedOn" element, but it neither specify how to deal with multiple instance of this element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made tests, and it seems that MS Word only deals with the last occurence of the "basedOn" element. If I have this style definition:

```
<w:style w:type="character" w:default="1" w:styleId="Underline">
  <w:name w:val="Underline"/>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:u w:val="single"/>
  </w:rPr>
</w:style>
<w:style w:type="character" w:styleId="Blue">
  <w:name w:val="Blue"/>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:color w:val="0000FF"/>
  </w:rPr>
</w:style>
<w:style w:type="character" w:styleId="BlueUnderline">
  <w:name w:val="BlueUnderline"/>
  <w:basedOn w:val="Blue"/>
  <w:basedOn w:val="Underline"/>
</w:style>
```

The run which I apply the style on is underlined but not blue. Considering I want to reproduce the Word's behaviour, this is what I decided to do.